# Find Replace all values in a column Google script/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to find multiple values in all cells in a column and replace them with different values

IF I only have one value to find/replace my function works great

```
function FindReplace() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var col = [].concat.apply([], ss.getRange(2,3,ss.getLastRow()).getValues()); 
  
  ss.getRange(2,3,ss.getLastRow()).setValues(col.map(fr));
  
  function fr(input){
    return [input.replace("something","something else")];
  }
 
}
```

But I need to find all values in a list and replace them from a different list the lists can have n elements

`var ifind = ["This", "That", "The other"];`

and replace them with a different list

`var ireplace = ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC"];`

I have been trying to use map() or forEeach() within the following to do this but to no avail

```
function findreplace(input){
  var ifind = ["This", "That", "The other"];
  var ireplace = ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC"];

    return [input.replace(ifind ,ireplace)];
  }
```

I know I can use a loop for the whole process but trying to learn new things and this looked promising or at least an interesting approach

Thanks

Comment: If your goal is to learn to use `map()` and `forEach()` and you know how to do what you want with a loop, then I suggest you first implement it with a loop. If you then can't figure out how to modify to use the array methods, then please update your question with your code and the SO community will be more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) or [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) would be a better data structure for 1 to 1 relationships. You can use it along with [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to loop over all keys in the object and replace it one by one accumulating the  result:

```
function findReplace_mod1() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  /*No flat*/ const col = /* [].concat.apply([], */ ss
    .getRange(2, 3, ss.getLastRow())
    .getValues(); /* ) */

  const map = { This: 'AAA', That: 'BBB' };
  const iFinds = Object.keys(map);
  ss.getRange(2, 3, ss.getLastRow()).setValues(col.map(fr));

  function fr(input) {
    return [iFinds.reduce((str, k) => str.replace(k, map[k]), input[0])];
  }
}
```

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/
function findReplace_mod1() {
  const col = [['This is a cat'], ['This is not That']];
  const map = { This: 'AAA', That: 'BBB' };
  const iFinds = Object.keys(map);
  console.info(col.map(fr));

  function fr(input) {
    return [iFinds.reduce((str, k) => str.replace(k, map[k]), input[0])];
  }
}

findReplace_mod1();
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I like what you did. I can follow everything but this `return [iFinds.reduce((str, k) => str.replace(k, map[k]), input[0])]` but I will work on figuring that out. Also, I will use this with your excellent function to cobine my list into a object `var map = {};
  ifind.forEach(function(item, i) {
    map[item] = ireplace[i];
  });`  Thank you!