# In delimited string replace substring between the delimiters only if the substring matches replacement value

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to in a delimited string, replace substring between the delimiters only if the substring matches the replacement value

Using this in Google sheets

The matching

```
var ifind = ["AA", "CaaL"];
var ireplace = ["zz", "Bob"];

zz replaces AA
Bob replaces CaaL
```

I have

```
| Id | Segment            |
|----|--------------------|
| 1  | AAA AA|AA|CaaL AA  |
| 2  | AAA-AA|AA|CaaL     |
| 3  | AAA, AA|AA|AA      |
| 4  | AA                 |
| 5  | AA AA              |
| 6  | AA, AA             |
| 7  |                    |
| 8  | CaaL               |
| 9  | AA                 |
```

I need

```
| Id | Segment           |
|----|-------------------|
| 1  | AAA AA|zz|CaaL AA |
| 2  | AAA-AA|zz|Bob     |
| 3  | AAA, AA|zz|zz     |
| 4  | zz                |
| 5  | AA AA             |
| 6  | AA, AA            |
| 7  |                   |
| 8  | Bob               |
| 9  | zz                |
```

I have tried (amongst other things)

```
return [iFinds.reduce((str, k) => str.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+k+'\\b','g'),map[k]), input[0])];

and

 return [iFinds.reduce((str, k) => str.replace(new RegExp('(?![ .,]|^)?(\\b' + k + '\\b)(?=[., ]|$)','g'),map[k]), input[0])];

and

return [iFinds.reduce((str, k) => str.split(k).join (map[k]), input[0])];
```

My function (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65041222/find-replace-all-values-in-a-column-google-script-javascript))

```
function findReplace_mod1() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const col = ss.getRange(2, 3, ss.getLastRow()).getValues();
  
  var ifind = ["AA", "Caal"];
  var ireplace = ["zz", "Bob"];
  
  var map = {};
  ifind.forEach(function(item, i) {
    map[item] = ireplace[i];
  });
  
  //const map = { Fellow: 'AAA', bob: 'BBB' };
  const iFinds = Object.keys(map);
  ss.getRange(2, 3, ss.getLastRow()).setValues(col.map(fr));

  function fr(input) {
    return [iFinds.reduce((str, k) => str.replace(k, map[k]), input[0])];
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your fixed function can look like

```js
function findReplace_mod1() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const col = ss.getRange(2, 3, ss.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var ifind = ["AA", "CaaL"];
  var ireplace = ["zz", "Bob"];
  
  var map = {};
  ifind.forEach(function(item, i) {
    map[item] = ireplace[i];
  });
  
  //const map = { Fellow: 'AAA', bob: 'BBB' };
  const regex = new RegExp("(?<![^|])(?:" + ifind.join("|") + ")(?![^|])", "g");
  ss.getRange(2, 3, ss.getLastRow()).setValues(col.map(fr));

  function fr(input) {
    return input.map(c => c.replace(regex, (x) => map[x]));
  }
}
```

The pattern will look like

```js
/(?<![^|])(?:AA|CaaL)(?![^|])/g
```

where

- `(?<![^|])` - is a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a `|` or start of a string immediately to the left of the current location
- `(?:AA|CaaL)` - a `AA` or `CaaL`
- `(?![^|])` - is a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a `|` or end of a string immediately to the right of the current location.

See [the regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/bUgO7L/1) (negative lookarounds are replaced with positive ones since the demo is run against a single multiline string, not a set of separate strings).

Comment: Thank you, Wiktor, that sorted it as well as the explination

Comment: Wiktor, could you explain this part  `(x) => map[x]` I can not figure out what is going on here, in particular, what is `(x)` ? Thank you

Comment: @Einarr I should have changed your variable names, they are confusing. You defined your own `map` variable that contains `ifind` values to search for and `ireplace` with corresponding replacements. So, `.replace(regex, (x) => map[x])`  means that once a regex finds a match, `x` is assigned the match value, and the match value is used as the key to find the corresponding value of the `map` "dictionary".

Comment: Ha!, I understand now. This seems a valuable thing to know. Thank you again

Answer (score 2):

The string to replace

- starts with `|` or start of the string `^`
- ends with `|` or end of the string `$`

The regex needs to be

```
str.replace(new Regexp(`(\\||^)${k}(\\||$)`), `$1${map[k]}$2`)
```

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/
function findReplace_mod2() {
  const col = [['AAA AA|AA|CaaL AA'], ['AA'], ['AAA-AA|AA|CaaL']];
  const map = { AA: 'zz', CaaL: 'Bob' };
  const iFinds = Object.keys(map);
  console.info(col.map(fr));

  function fr(input) {
    return [iFinds.reduce((str, k) => str.replace(new RegExp(`(\\||^)${k}(\\||$)`), `$1${map[k]}$2`), input[0])];
  }
}

findReplace_mod2();
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: TheMaster, very close! it fails if there is more then one match `AA|AA|AA` this becomes `zz|AA|AA` but should be `zz|zz|zz` my apologies if I failed to indicate that

Comment: It seems to not match `consecutive patterns` so  `AA|AA` gives `zz|AA` and `AA|AA|AA` gives `zz|AA|zz` I have been trying to figure out how to alter the pattern but not getting it.  Further assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @Einarr I see you have a good answer from Wiktor. Glad your issue is resolved