# Restrict Find and Replace function using map() to single column in a 2d array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, google-apps-script

I am working in Google sheets

I have a find and replace function gotten from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65063302/in-delimited-string-replace-substring-between-the-delimiters-only-if-the-substri).  It works great when the array is made from a single column of data

But, in certain instances in which I want to use my function I have all my data sitting in an array which is being passed from prior processing, the data if printed to the page looks like

```
| Id | Segment            |Other Column| etc..
|----|--------------------|------------|
| 1  | AAA AA|AA|CaaL AA  |stuff       |
| 2  | AAA-AA|AA|CaaL     |stuff       |
| 3  | AAA, AA|AA|AA      |AA          |
| 4  | AA                 |stuff       | 
| 5  | AA AA              |            |
| 6  | AA, AA             |AA          |
| 7  |                    |stuff       |
| 8  | CaaL               |stuff       |
| 9  | AA                 |stuff       |
```

I only want to replace data in the `Segment` column

```
| Id | Segment           ||Other Column| etc..
|----|-------------------|------------|
| 1  | AAA AA|zz|CaaL AA |stuff       |
| 2  | AAA-AA|zz|Bob     |stuff       |
| 3  | AAA, AA|zz|zz     |AA          |
| 4  | zz                |stuff       |
| 5  | AA AA             |            |
| 6  | AA, AA            |AA          |
| 7  |                   |stuff       |
| 8  | Bob               |stuff       |
| 9  | zz                |stuff       |
```

As it is the `AA` in the `Other Column` (could be in any column, I have no way of knowing) is being replaced which I do not want

Can the findReplace function be restricted to a single column in values updating that only that column in `values` ?

I have tried getting the column array I want to restrict values to with

```
function getColumn(matrix, col, startrow){
       var column = [];
       for(var i=startrow; i<matrix.length; i++){
          column.push(matrix[i][col]);
       }
       return column;
}
```

and then attempting to restrict the input to this column

```
function fr(input) {
    const aCOL = getColumn(values,2,0)
    return input.aCOL.map(c => c.replace(regex, (x) => map[x]));
    
AND
   
   return input.map(c => c.aCOL.map(y => y.replace(regex, (x) => map[x])));

  }
```

I get  `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Thanks

```
function findReplace(values) {

  var search_for   = ["AA", "Caal"];
  var replace_with = ["zz", "yy"];
  
  var map = {};
  search_for.forEach(function(item, i) {
    map[item] = replace_with[i];
  });
  //map = { AA: 'zz', Caal: 'yy' };

  const regex = new RegExp("(?<![^|])(?:" + search_for.join("|") + ")(?![^|])", "g");
  
  range.setValues(values.map(fr));

  function fr(input) {
    return input.map(c => c.replace(regex, (x) => map[x]));
  }
}
```

Comment: where exactly do you define `input` ? and why did you use `map` for a variable ? while it is okay to do that, it is confusing since there is a built in method `map` which you also use later in your code.

Comment: What is that you wish to  acomplish with your script? Please show examples of input and output.

Comment: I updated the question with the hoped-for output

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. Can I ask you about the detail of `in certain instances in which I want to use my function`? 2. What is `values` of `getColumn(values,2,0)` and `findReplace(values)`?

Answer (score 1):

The code you got from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65065543/3751868) works fine if you just change the range you're retrieving. So instead of creating a function to extract the column into an array, you can just adjust the range.

If the column you want to replace ('Segment') is the second one, then you can do the following changes.

From:

```
const col = ss.getRange(2, 3, ss.getLastRow()).getValues();
...
ss.getRange(2, 3, ss.getLastRow()).setValues(col.map(fr));
```

To:

```
const col = ss.getRange(2, 2, ss.getLastRow()).getValues();
...
ss.getRange(2, 2, ss.getLastRow()).setValues(col.map(fr));
```